# How come my program keeps crashing when I try to run it?

Tags: c

I am a beginner programmer (about a week) and my simple program keeps crashing. What did I do wrong? It crashes before I even input the amount of hours. Please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int hours;
float wage;
float total[2];

int main()

{

    printf("How many hours have you worked this week?\n");
    fgets(hours, sizeof(hours), stdin);
    sscanf(hours,"%d", &wage);

    if (hours < 40)
        wage = 8.5;
        total[0] = hours * wage;

    printf("You will earn %d dollars", total[0]);

    if (hours >= 40)
        wage = 12.75;
        total[1] = hours * wage;

    printf("You will earn %d dollars", total[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You didn't get any single variable input or output right, no wonder it crashes...

Comment: you miss brackets in your if conditions or you made your tabulators wrong

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is here:

```
fgets(hours, sizeof(hours), stdin);
```

`fgets` doesn't do formatted input, so this will end up crashing in Cruel and Unusual Ways as it tries to use the integer value `hours` as a pointer to a buffer that should be read.

To fix this, try this:

```
scanf("%d", &hours);
```

You also have a completely unnecessary and malformed `scanf` on the next line:

```
sscanf(hours,"%d", &wage);
```

The syntax for `scanf` is

```
scanf(formatting-string, destinations...);
```

Therefore, it should probably look like this:

```
scanf("%f", &wage);
```

You should definitely crank up the warning level on your compiler; I'm amazed that this compiled without giving you a warning explaining that something fishy was going on.

There's also an issue with your formatting specifiers in the `printf` statements:

```
printf("You will earn %d dollars", total[0]);
```

Note that `total[0]` is a `float`, not an `int`, so `%d` is inappropriate. Try using `%f` instead.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It produces a few warnings actually.

Comment: You are still missing the incredible sscanf.

Comment: @user2980300- Please be more specific. What *is* it doing? What have *you* tried to do to resolve the issue? Right now, you're posting what appears to be a homework assignment that has glaring errors in it and asking us to fix it for you without having demonstrated any basic effort to fix it yourself. Please describe what you've tried. Have you used a debugger? Have you added debugging printouts?

Answer (score 2):

`hour` is defined `int` but you are initializing it with `fgets` which is used for inputting strings.
Use

```
scanf("%d", &hours);
```

Also use `%f` instead of `%d` in all of your `printf` statements and so with `sscanf` otherwise your programs behavior will **Undefined**.

### 7.21.6 Formatted input/output functions

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.282) If any argument is
> not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
> undefined.

Comment: @MatteoItalia; Oops! I missed that!

Answer (score 1):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/

fgets gets a char pointer as first argument... you give a int. Thats why it crashes

Answer (score 0):

`fgets` expects its first argument to be a pointer to the first element of an array of `char`, which will hold the input.  For example:

```
char hoursBuf[4]; //room for 3 digits plus 0 terminator
if ( !fgets( hoursBuf, sizeof hoursBuf, stdin ))
{
  // error on input; you really want to verify that your library calls
  // succeed before moving on. 
}
```

This will save the input as a *string*, or a sequence of characters; in order to perform calculations with it, you will have to convert it to an integer type using another function like `strtol` or `sscanf`.

You could avoid the conversion step by using `scanf` directly:

```
if ( scanf( "%d", &hours ) == 1 )
{
  ...
}
```

`scanf` will return the number of successful conversions and assignments; in the case above, it should be 1.  If it's 0, then the user typed in something other than a valid integer.  However, if they type in something like "12w", `scanf` will convert and assign the "12" to `hours`, return 1, and leave the `w` in the input stream to foul up the next input.

I prefer using `strtol` because it catches those cases:

```
char *chk; // will point to the first character not converted 
int tmp = (int) strtol( hoursBuf, &chk, 10 );

if ( !isspace( *chk ) && *chk != 0 )
{
  // *chk is not whitespace or 0, meaning the user typed an invalid character
  fprintf( stderr, "%s is not a valid integer string\n", hoursBuf );
}
else
{
  // input was good, so we assign hours:
  hours = tmp;
}
```

I know this is a lot to take in for someone who's been programming for about a week.  I/O in C can *either* be "simple" or "robust"; you don't get both.